# For which values $p, q$ does one have $L^{p} \subset L^{q}$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1912546/fourier-operator-mathcalflp-mathbbt-rightarrow-ellp-mathbb-z) seems to suggest that one has $L^{p}([-\pi,\pi]) \subset L^{1}([-\pi,\pi])$ for every $p \in (1,2)$. There are some obvious cases where this does not hold: for instance, not every $L^{1}$-integrable function is also $L^4$-integrable, and common counterexamples are functions involving square roots and characteristic functions.

However, if $p,q$ are any real numbers (so that if, for instance, $p \in \mathbb{N}$, then the norm $\| \cdot \|_p$ on $L^p$ defines a quasi-norm rather than a norm), can we find pairs $(p,q)$, with $p \neq q$, such that one has $L^p([a,b]) \subset L^q([a,b])$ for any (or a particular choice of) $a$ and $b$, with $a < b$? If $p, q \in \mathbb{N}$, do any pairs exist, and if so, how many?

Is there an analogous result for $l^p$ spaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For any finite measure space $X$, one has $L^q(X)\subset L^p(X)$ for $0<p\leq q\leq\infty$.

This is a *theorem* in real analysis. (See for instance Folland's Real Analysis Proposition 6.12.) In this theorem, there is no assumption about whether $p,q$ are integers or not.

When $X=[-\pi,\pi]$, $L^p(X)\subset L^1(X)$ for any $p>1$, and in particular for $p\in (1,2)$.

"not every $L^1$ function is $L^4$" does not serve as a counterexample.

On the other hand, 
if $A$ is *any* set, and $0<p<q\leq\infty$, then $\ell^p(A)\subset\ell^q(A)$. See Proposition 6.11 in Follands real analysis.

---

[image]

Comment: Could you provide a link/reference to show me where this is proved?

Comment: @user363087 Let $E= \{|f|\ge 1\}.$  Compare $\int_E|f|^q, \int_E|f|^p.$

Comment: @user363087: Please see the edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, if $p<q$, you have $L^q(a,b)\subset L^p(a,b),$ when your interval is bounded. More generally, if $X$ is a space of finite measure, than also $L^q(X)\subset L^p(X).$

For the spaces $l^p$, it's the other way around: if $p<q$, then $l^p\subset l^q.$